# Is this a valid url parameter in jquery.ajax()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, codeigniter

Is this a valid url parameter in jquery.ajax(),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    getRecordspage();
  });

  function getRecordspage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/index.php/adminController/mainAccount",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        global:false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
           alert(jsonobj);
        }
    });
}
 </script>
```

The url doesn't seem to go to my controller function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting async to `true`. Also, what does Firebug say?

Always use [Firebug](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CAkQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Ffirefox%2Faddons%2Fversions%2F1843&rct=j&q=firebug&ei=GfW6S4bDC5SkmwPuyaXVCA&usg=AFQjCNFuN2ASosqZBcyfbRvVw-jTS2kL9w) to see what's actually going on.

[image: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/images/p/11828/]

Answer (score 1):

You're using something like mod_rewrite I asume. You should use a direct url (http://www.example.nl/page.php) I meant it is allowed to use get variables in your url...

Comment: @dodo as i am using codeigniter i want to call a controller function how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can create you own page (eg. http://www.example.com/myPageToCall.php) and this page simulates a call to a controller function with something like curl... I'm not familiar with codeigniter so I can't give you the exact solution that is something you have to do on your own ;)

Answer (score 1):

in your url try just function name 
url:"main"